# Почему нет запятой или тире в предложении "Главное не улыбайтесь"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*– Если московиты будут вас о чем-то спрашивать, отвечайте что взбредет в голову, – напутствовал Бромли окоченевшую барышню. – Переводчик – человек наш, он переведет как должно. **Главное не улыбайтесь.** У московитов улыбка почитается знаком слабости*  (Б. Акунин).

**Почему нет запятой или тире** в этом предложении? Ошибка корректора или авторская пунктуация?

**А зачем** здесь такая пунктуация?

Или можно как-то иначе **объяснить** отсутствие знаков?

Comment: Может, пунктуация?

Comment: Непонятно, что имеете в виду. Это авторский вариант или ошибка корректора?

Comment: Ещё одна орфография осталась)

Comment: Орфография – это еще и общее название правописания (правильно пишу). Так что хорош придираться, лучше ответ дайте. Стали бы на месте автора запятую ставить? А можно это как-нибудь к правилам можно привязать? У меня была вообще-то идея...

Comment: Да? Но оно почти всегда используется в плане правильности букв в словах, а то все будут путаться. Должно быть всё чётко.

Comment: Ну ладно, я же в одном месте исправила. А теперь ответ...

Comment: Жаль, что ответы на сложные вопросы мало кто понимает.

Comment: Вы хотели ещё ответ, вот он вам.

Comment: Один из плюсов за вопрос мой, если что.

Comment: Я знаю, у меня дар ясновидения на этот счет. Ну и за ответ уж добавьте, не мелочитесь.

Comment: Так я ж в оппозиции. Но вы хоть согласны с моим вторым ответом (не с комментарием)?

Answer (score 1):

Казалось бы, очередная ошибка у Акунина, ничего интересного, но нет, здесь не всё так просто.

Корректор, скорее всего, посчитал, что здесь действует правило Розенталя о частице "не" перед сказуемым (тогда тире не ставится), но это не тот случай.

Так могло бы получиться, если был бы инфинитив. Контекст:
*— Надо улыбаться?

— Нет, главное не улыбаться, главное — делать умный вид.*

Должно подразумеваться противопоставление для этого. Так и в примерах Розенталя. А здесь нет такого:
*Главное не {улыбаться}, а что-то другое.*
А у нас:
*Главное — {не улыбайтесь}.*
Либо:
*Главное, {не улыбайтесь}.*

Как заметил, не особо получается сделать отрицание с глаголом в повелительном наклонении в таких случаях:
*Самое важное — купи хлеб.* || Нормально.
*Самое важное — не купи хлеб[, а купи сметану].* || Не нормально, если воспринимать как подлежащее, а не как вводное с интонационным тире.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137967/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd--------).

Answer (score 1):

Сложная это тема. Но реально объяснить более доходчиво.

Возьмём такой пример:
*Главное — незнание.* || Частицы "не" здесь нет, поэтому тире нужно. Противопоставление с А здесь сделать не получится
А теперь так:
*Главное не знание[, а понимание].* || Здесь частица "не" есть и тире можно не ставить. Сюда уже можно добавить союз А и сделать противопоставление.

Так вот, если в этих двух случаях существительное заменить на инфинитив, "не" по-любому будет писаться отдельно (потому что "не" с этим глаголом пишется отдельно), но смысл и пунктуация будут отличаться, как и раньше:
*Главное — не знать (незнание).* || Мы утверждаем, противопоставление с А здесь не подходит. Тире требуется.
*Главное не знать (не знание)[, а понимать].* || Здесь отрицаем, поэтому тире не требуется, как и в случае с существительным.

Comment: Вы все очень усложняете. Сейчас уже поздно, а завтра я вам объясню свою версию, почему там нет знаков. Вот и обсудим решение. Идет?

Comment: Там должен быть знак. Раскрываю в этом ответе смежную с вопросом тему. Наличие тире перед инфинитивом с частицей "не".

Comment: Зачем раскрываете? Мне нужен короткий и ясный ответ. Вот давайте завтра:  один ответ ваш, а другой мой. Соревнование!

Comment: Чтобы все поняли. Короткий и ясный ответ: знак должен стоять.

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть "Адвокат дьявола". Вот вы здесь пытаетесь то же самое сделать. Уже в который раз...

Comment: Ваш ответ я не считаю верным. Адвокат дьявола: «Тщеславие — мой самый любимый из грехов»? Это я вас (и остальных участников) искушаю? А как и зачем? Объясните подробнее.

Comment: Что именно, по-вашему, неверно? Этот ответ не ответ на ваш вопрос, а объяснение ситуации с инфинитивом, которого в примере Акунина нет.

Comment: Неверно: знак ДОЛЖЕН стоять. Верно: знак НЕ ДОЛЖЕН стоять.  Слово "главное" не обособляется в функции наречия, то есть имеет обстоятельствённое значение. Вы  (или кто-то еще) можете доказать, что там нет обстоятельственного значения?

Comment: Это вам нужно доказывать, что оно есть) Так дела не будет, у вас взгляды слишком часто меняются, это плохая черта для филолога/учёного. В вопросе вы против отсутствия знака, по крайней мере, не считаете это нормой. Адвокат дьявола оправдывал виновных, они выходили на свободу, а вы оправдываете ошибки и виновных в их совершении. И довольно часто.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь поняла. Я оправдываю ошибки виновных. Забавно! А если они невиновны, а вы их камнями закидали, то тогда я кто?

Comment: Виновны, виновны. Давайте устроим суд присяжных.

Comment: Не, эти не разберутся.  Зовите уж самого Акунина, я-то с ним не знакома.

Comment: Но вы-то хорошо знакомы с его творчеством (не то что я), можете наладить контакт.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, ответ.

**1. Пауза не допускается**

***Главное не улыбАйтесь**. У московитов улыбка почитается знаком слабости.*

Это инструктаж, причем короткий – времени очень мало. Два предложения связаны причинно-следственной связью и одной темой, нужен **быстрый переход** от одной мысли к другой.

Поэтому пауза не допускается, никакая.  Но в первом предложении **всего два слова.** Если поставить запятую после вводного «главное», пауза в любом случае будет обозначена. Значит, первое слово обособлять **очень нежелательно.**

**2. Как  объяснить отсутствие знака**

Мы знаем, что большинство вводных слов имеет **парные наречия**, которые не обособляются. Тогда «главное» здесь **следует считать наречием** с обстоятельственным значением. Это и есть короткое объяснение.

Замена обстоятельством-синонимом возможна, например: *Ни в коем случае не улыбайтесь.* Или: *Обязательно улыбайтесь*  (в утвердительном варианте).

Также возможен вариант с частицей: *Только не улыбайтесь.*

Но значение **наречия даже указано в словаре**: Главным образом, в зн. нареч. Преимущественно, в основном. Давит главным образом быт. Собрались главным образом ветераны.

**3. Пример**

***Главное не оглЯдывайся,** иначе тебя заметят. Иди быстро, уверенно.*

В таком тексте пауза тоже нежелательна (быстрое развитие темы).

Comment: В этих примерах "главным образом" = "по большей мере" ≠ "главное". На "главное" "главным образом" не заменить.

Comment: Вам бы только что-то на что-то менять. Почему вы не можете смотреть на проблему обобщенно. Я просто показываю, что такое сочетание может иметь обстоятельственное значение в принципе. А в данном конкретном случае форма "главное" имеет значение наречия, а не вводного слова. С этим вы согласны?  Развивайте свободнее мышление.

Comment: Может иметь? Ну тогда замените на другое наречие (раз в словарях нет такого). Этот принцип широко используется в лингвистике. И будет вам доказательство. Хотя я не считаю, что можно доказать, что 2 + 2 = 5.

Comment: Ваши способы мне давно известны: поменять, переставить, изъять.  Вы работает с формой, а не с содержанием. У меня другой УРОВЕНЬ АНАЛИЗА обобщить значение одной формы и применить это значение в другой форме.  И я не боюсь сделать новый шаг там, где остановились все остальные

Comment: Это не мои способы, а широко применимые. Их используют Грамота и Розенталь. Давайте, если не хотим пауз, все вводные слова будем считать наречиями и запятых не ставить. А почему нет?

Comment: *И я не боюсь сделать новый шаг там, где остановились все остальные* — вы ходите по лезвию.

Comment: Ещё вам один способ доказательства: у наречия и вводного слова значения должны хоть чуть-чуть отличаться.

Comment: А вы стоите в общей толпе.  За голубями понаблюдайте. Если все едят, то к ним охотно присоединяются другие. Но бросьте им крошки немного в стороне. Стоят, смотрят, головами вертят... Это ваша реакция.

Comment: Это ваши фантазии. Там не всегда правит семантика.

Comment: Потому что за толпой в данном случае истина. И так обычно и происходит.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, поговорим еще. Как вы думаете, мне кто-нибудь плюсик за ответ поставит? Какой-нибудь смелый голубь?

Comment: Разве что после прочтения вашего комментария о плюсике. Вот вам контакты самого Акунина, спросите у него лично: https://www.facebook.com/borisakunin Может, станете его корректором после этого.